# Not able to deploy flask app on shared hosting [godaddy server]

Tags: python, flask

I have created a subdomain named flask.

These are the files with permission.

ls /home//public_html/flask

```
drwxr-x---   ../
drwxr-xr-x   cgi-bin/
-rwxr-xr-x   myapp.py
-rwxrwxrwx   run.cgi
-rw-r--r--   .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x   ./
```

**myapp.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**run.cgi**

```
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from restapplication import app

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/<user>/public_html/flask/run.cgi/$1
```

I tried flask.domainname.com, domainname.com/flask, but no luck.

Also no logs in error logs.

What can be the issue? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the web server process run as your userid, or as a generic webserver account id?

Comment: What response do you get from the browser?  404 not found?  500 server error?

Comment: This is 500 Internal Server Error error. I run trhs webserver using python myapp.py,   Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: What webserver are you using?  Apache?  Nginx?

Comment: its apache web server.

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error from Apache, then there should be something in the error log.

Comment: Long back I documented all the steps and wrote it on my website. I have  put all the steps in [Medium - here](https://medium.com/@mohdejazsiddiqui/deploy-flask-app-in-apache-shared-hosting-5b3c82c8fd5e). Hope it helps.